# LINQ request with Join to new object - very poor performance

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

```
var report = await db.Journal.AsNoTracking().Join(db.Users.AsNoTracking(),
                     (x => x.ClientUserId),
                     (y => y.UserId),
                     ((x, y) => new { Journal = x, Users = y }))
                        .Where(z => z.Journal.TotalTime >= 1 && z.Users.UserCompanies_id == companyId &&
                             z.Journal.DoneAt >= fromDateTime && z.Journal.DoneAt <= toDateTime)
                     .GroupBy(e => e.Users.UserId)
                     .Select(e => new ReportViewModel()
                     {
                         UserId = e.Key,
                         TimeSpendCCM = e.Sum(s => s.Journal.TotalTime),
                         //DateOfBirthday = e.FirstOrDefault().Users.DateOfBirthday
                     }).ToListAsync();
```

The problem is in DateOfBirthday. This line of code take 4 sec!!! 
When I removed DateOfBirthday then all request take about 150-200ms. When I added DateOfBirthday again request take about 4 sec. What I am doing wrong?

Database - MSSQL, ORM - Entity Framework

Comment: Try `GroupBy(e => new { e.Users.UserId, e.Users.DateOfBirthday })` and `UserId = e.Key.UserId, ..., DateOfBirthday = e.Key.DateOfBirthday`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. But if I need a lot of such fields can I use like this   .GroupBy(e => new { e.Users.UserId, e.Users.DateOfBirthday, e.Users.LastName, e.Users.FirstName .....})  ?

Comment: As long as they don't make the grouping narrower than `UserId`, yes.

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to get data from another table with foreign key I added GroupBy(....e.Users.ReportsInfo). But  I get this error - The key selector type for the call to the 'GroupBy' method is not comparable in the underlying store provider.

Comment: There must be primitive types in the grouping.

Comment: Ok. I have last one problem - Care = h.FirstOrDefault().Users.ReportsInfo.Count > 0 ? h.FirstOrDefault().Users.ReportsInfo.FirstOrDefault().PlanUpdatedAt : null And it take about 4 sec. Can you advice me please something to improve performance?